# Использование SSH ключа не работает в GitBash

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-bash

Развернут GitLab на своем сервере, там есть репозиторий который я пытаюсь клонировать. SSH ключи настроены. Я нахожусь под Windows. На команду в cmd ssh.exe git@хххххх.space GitLab отвечает "Welcome to GitLab, @root!"

GitBash:

```
Pavel@PAVELMAIN MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Laser
$ git clone git@хххххх.space:gitlab-instance-f8c5d114/lasermark.git
Cloning into 'lasermark'...
git@хххххх.space's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@хххххх.space's password:
```

Итог: с ключами проблема.

Главное что, GitLab в cmd отвечает welcome. Но если удалить ключ из GitLab то и в консоли появляется таже проблема. **Т.е. в cmd все нормально, а в Git Bash нет.** Спасибо предыдущим комментаторам.

cmd c ключом на сервере

```
PS C:\Users\Pavel> ssh.exe git@хххххх.space
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Pavel/.ssh/id_rsa':
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, @root!
Connection to ххххххх.space closed.
```

удалил ключ

```
PS C:\Users\Pavel> ssh.exe git@ххххххх.space
git@ххххххх.space's password:
```

Отчасти проблема решна, вызов git clone через командную строку работает штатно.
Проблема с Git Bash ?? И не подумал бы на самом деле если бы не увидел welcome в cmd.

На счет тории разных ключей при использовании Git Bash. Подумал идея хорошая и решил проверить.
Нашел статью: https://gist.github.com/bsara/5c4d90db3016814a3d2fe38d314f9c23
Слепое повторение, не помогло. Но удалось посмотреть через Git GUI что он смотрит в правильный открытый ключ. Ну наверное тогда и в закрытый тоже смотрит правильно но не факт?

После вышеуказанной статьи пошел проверять ssh-agent так как там решение проблемы уходит в его запуск. Плохо знаю что это, но как я понял эта служба связана с хранением/обработкой ssh ключей. Обнаружил что она не работает. Починил так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113738/starting-ssh-agent-on-windows-10-fails-unable-to-start-ssh-agent-service-erro
Потом добавил туда свой ключ и проверил что он там есть:

```
PS C:\Users\Pavel> Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
PS C:\Users\Pavel> ssh-agent.exe
PS C:\Users\Pavel> Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent


PS C:\Users\Pavel> ssh-add.exe -l
The agent has no identities.
PS C:\Users\Pavel> ssh-add.exe "C:\Users\Pavel\.ssh\id_rsa"
Identity added: C:\Users\Pavel\.ssh\id_rsa (pavel@PAVELMAIN)
PS C:\Users\Pavel> ssh-add.exe -l
3072 SHA256:wKlS5nPATC4MgEJkup7N94A8WZIdSN8HSLcbmnPbuBA pavel@PAVELMAIN (RSA)
PS C:\Users\Pavel>
```

И о чудо, здесь ключ не соответствует ожиданиям!(и с секретным сравнил тоже).
Правильный открытый ключ(из git GUI) но не правильный закрытый? Они вроде как связаны математически. И как тут работает ssh-agent? Как он связан с Git Bash? Пока это все что есть.

Comment: Он просит пароль от SSH. Таки ключи не настроены.

Comment: PS. довольно глупо замазывать адрес в одном месте и оставлять в остальных

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html

Comment: Да да, я видимо очень тупой сегодня, видимо слишком устал. Что ж буду дальше гуглить почему ключи не настроены. Хотя странно что сервер отвечает на git@хххххх.space > "Welcome to GitLab, @root!"

Comment: *"На команду ssh.exe git@хххххх.space GitLab отвечает Welcome to GitLab, @root!"* - значит ключи не настроены

Comment: Тут уже был "docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html". Странно, мне казалось, что если ключи не настроены то он не должен отвечать, или уж как минимум не Welcome. Ладно буду перечитывать все по второму кругу.

Comment: Сильно подозреваю что ваш git и ssh.exe используют разный ssh и/или разные ключи. Гуглите лучше как настраивать git под винду.

Comment: Ахаха пока я разбирался с этим, сломал и то что работало в консоли!!xD Я уже не могу xD почему просто нельзя сложить ключи в одно место xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, Git в Windows тащит за собой собственный SSH со своими настройками и видимо директорией для ключей (не нашел где, хотя где конфиги нашел). **Вообщем одно из решений** переустановка Git с параметрами использования стороннего SSH сервера. Тогда Git Bash будет использовать дефолтный SSH в Windows. И понятно где конфиги и ключи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]